# Java "this", inherited v passed. Is there a difference?

Tags: java, android

I have a class and within the class are some constructors (1 of the three shown) and some methods. I saw some potential shortcuts in that I could use some of the methods within the constructors. Android Studio doesn't complain nor does the build.

1) Does `this` get recognized as being inherited within a method when called from a constructor? (I assume so) *<<=== 001 in the code*

2) (a) Will changes applied to variables by a method called from the constructor apply those to the object being constructed when referenced by `this` or (b) when not referenced by `this` but by a passed parameter? *I guess all other <<=== nnn apply*

Of course if there are blaring mistakes and or misconceptions then I'd also appreciated them being pointed out.

Anyway here's the code (Note an extract of the class).

```
// Full constructor
public DBColumn(String column_name, String column_type, boolean primary_index, String default_value) {
    column_type = column_type.toUpperCase();
    column_name = column_name.toLowerCase();

    // Lots of potential values for the column type; so validate
    boolean column_ok = false;
    this.column_type = simplifyColumnType(column_type);                              //<<=== 001
    this.column_name = column_name;
    this.checkDBColumnIsUsable(this,"DBColumn (Full)");                              //<<=== 001
    this.primary_index = primary_index;
    this.default_value = default_value;
}

public void setDBColumnName(String column_name) {                                    //<<=== 002
    this.column_name = column_name;                                                  //<<=== 002
    this.checkDBColumnIsUsable(this,"setDBColumnName");
}

public void setDBColumnType(String column_type) {
    this.column_type = simplifyColumnType(column_type);                              //<<=== 003
    this.checkDBColumnIsUsable(this,"setDBColumnType");
}

private boolean checkDBColumnIsUsable(DBColumn dbcolumn, String caller) {            //<<=== 004
    if(!dbcolumn.usable) {
        if(dbcolumn.column_name.length() > 0 & dbcolumn.column_type.length() > 0) {
            dbcolumn.usable = true;
            dbcolumn.problem_msg = "";
        }
    } else {
        dbcolumn.usable = false;                                                     //<<=== 005
        if(dbcolumn.column_name.length() < 1) {
            dbcolumn.problem_msg=dbcolumn.problem_msg + 
                    "EDBC001 - Invalid Column Name - Must be at least 1 character in length. Caller=(" + caller + ")";
        }
        if(dbcolumn.column_type.length() < 1) {
            dbcolumn.problem_msg=dbcolumn.problem_msg + 
                    "EDBC002 - Invalid Column Type - Must be a valid SQLite DATATYPE. Caller=(" + caller + ")";
        }
    }
    return dbcolumn.usable;
}
```

Comment: probably [variable scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)  will help you

Comment: A non-static method which takes a single instance of the enclosing class as an explicit parameter is odd: just remove that parameter and refer (maybe implicitly) to `this`; or make the method static.

Comment: @Andy perhaps odd but wrong or right as in will it or won't it work? Answers to my perceptions, however odd, is how I learn, perhaps that being odd as well :).

Comment: There is only one reference to any object and all references to that object are the same except perhaps the type of the reference.

Comment: @MikeT it will work, but it's error-prone: you actually have two references to `DBColumn` instances (`this` and `dbcolumn`); you might forget to qualify something (e.g. you write `usable = false` instead of `dbcolumn.usable = false`). This looks like it works right now, but there is a bug that would turn up if you started to use the method differently: you can now call `checkDBColumnIsUsable(somethingOtherThanThis, "")`, and you will overwrite `this.usable` instead of `somethingOtherThanThis.usable`. It is just safer to remove one of the two references, in either of the ways I have mentioned.

Comment: @Andy, many thanks in my odd way :) I understand what you are saying in a sort of normal way :).I will look at changing to statics.

Comment: @MikeT correct. I would prefer the remove-the-variable option, unless it is ever anticipated that you will want to call `checkDBColumnIsUsable(somethingOtherThanThis, "...")`, since it is less verbose.

Comment: @Andy, if you posted what you said as a summery. Then I'd accept it as the answer. At the minimum I'd vote you up. Perhaps my odd ways have come from the many odd programming languages I've utilised from Spectrum basic back, writing actual machine code for the Z80 without an assembler, through Forth, Pascal, lots and lots of Rexx and IBM assembly language to modern day OO's. So sometimes what some find simple gets confused amongst all those flavours floating around withint the pretty oldish grey matter. :)

Comment: @MikeT re EJP's point, I don't think that it can have compiled successfully. An explicit parameter called `this` would give a compile-time error, per [JLS sec 15.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3)

Comment: @Andy great informative link. However,  more confusion,/things for me to ponder, is the parameter part of the body as such? I can understand from a lexical point it's not in the body. However, the parameters themselves are intrinsic to the body, in a processing view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst it is not incorrect to pass an explicit `DBColumn` reference to `checkDBColumnIsUsable`, it is a style that I would advise against.

Because it is a member function, there is an implicit `DBColumn` instance already being passed to the method when you call it - `this`. For example, if you have a member function

```
private boolean checkDBColumnIsUsable(DBColumn dbcolumn, String caller) {
```

then it is invoked under the covers as if it were a static function like this:

```
private static boolean checkDBColumnIsUsable(DBColumn $this, DBColumn dbcolumn, String caller) {
```

What this means is that you actually have two references to `DBColumn` instances in the body of the method. In and of itself, that's not too much of a problem - sure, there is one more than you need, but the overhead is marginal to the point of being irrevelant.

However: you open yourself up to bugs like this. For instance, you might accidentally write:

```
usable = false;
```

instead of:

```
dbcolumn.usable = false;
```

For your current usage pattern, that looks like it works. However, if you were to add a new call in your code like:

```
checkDBColumnIsUsable(somethingOtherThanThis, "caller");
```

then the bug would manifest itself: `usable` would be set on `this`, not `somethingOtherThanThis`.

It can be argued that this is pointing out bugs that don't really exist. I would counter that programming defensively - so that bugs can't be introduced too - is a good strategy.

There are two options here:

1. Simply remove the `DBColumn dbcolumn` argument from the method, and then always refer to `this` (perhaps implicitly) in the method body;
2. Make the method static, removing the ability to refer (implicitly or explicitly) to `this`.

Either of these removes one of the unnecessary references. I would go for the first because it makes the code less verbose; you are still able to invoke the method for `somethingOtherThanThis` simply by calling `somethingOtherThanThis.checkDBColumnIsUsable("caller")`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes.
2. In your situation, the use of `this` is to scope your variables. Whenever you use `this.field` in a method (even in a constructor), it references the instance variable. If you use it without `this` then it can reference the argument parameter or a variable defined in the method first; only if there is none, then it would reference the instance variable.

Comment: @Arun, certainly the most enlightening response to date. It would be greatly appreciated if you could try to split the 2nd answer into A and B, that's if you can understand what I'm trying to ask.